# Text wont show inside a label nested in an AbsoluteLayout

Tags: android, html, typescript, nativescript

Im building a component to show users profile pictures stacked horizontally. 
in a case where user doesn't have a profile photo, his 1st name letter will show in a bubble inside the stack.

Im having difficulty showing the text inside the bubble.
the container for the bubble is a layout with circle class and inside of it a Label containing the text.

Would highly appreciate any help in this regards since it has exhausted me :XXX

code:

```
<AbsoluteLayout orientation="horizontal" style="background-color: #00fdd6">
<ng-template ngFor let-user [ngForOf]="users|limit:lengthLimit" let-i="index">
    <Image *ngIf="user.profile_photo" [src]="getImageUrl(user)" class="img-circle" height="50" width="50"
           left="{{stackProfilePhotos(i)}}"></Image>
    <RelativeLayout *ngIf="!user.profile_photo" style="border: #0000fe 5px solid; background-color: green;"
     class="img-circle" height="100" width="100" top="-25" left="{{stackProfileLetterBubble(i)}}">
        <Label text="M" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="24"></Label>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ng-template>
```

[Attached a view of the ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFR3S.jpg)